# File upload without page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, file-upload

I have a html page where I upload a file using form input.
My code is

```
  <form action = "UploadFile.jsp" method = "post" target="my-iframe"
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "file" size = "50" />
     <br />
     <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
  </form>
  <iframe name="my-iframe" src="UploadFile.jsp" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Now this form works good without any page refresh. But, I need to know if there are any other possible methods of file upload without using an iframe where there is no page refresh.
Is there any method to do this with ajax request and javascript?

Comment: You can read file by FileReader in javascript and send to server by ajax and put it in file by php.

Comment: Simply use Ajax. let me know if you need a code sample.

Comment: @W.Seun can you send me the code sample

Comment: I dont use php, but when i google for this I get the code only in php

Comment: I have found perfect code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31733232/573032).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function imgUpload(file){
var uploadRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    uploadRequest.open('post', 'demo-url');
    uploadRequest.file = file;
    uploadRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
      //or
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      "Response code is 200 i.e successful image upload";
    }
  };
    uploadRequest.send();
}
```

I will explain this as simple as possible, the first thing done is calling the XMLHttpRequest function and what it does is to make request without changing the state of your web-page, now from the top we've already passed the file value and send it as expected by the url/api, now due to the powerful ability of XMLHttpRequest, we will catch the response with the help of onreadystatechange as used about to determine the status of our request if good(200) or bad(404>) so we can at the same time notify on the same page of the browser using Jquery as so on. Yet I will advice you go through some rich tutorial on this, either youtube or some other websites, stackoverflow will simple help you share more light on it after going through the tutorials.